# "Delete operation is forbidden for current area" error while create customer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-address

I modified register page and added address fields. So, when user register address will be save.

But having this error when try to save customer.

```
Delete operation is forbidden for current area
```

When i removed this code - `<input name="create_address" value="1" type="hidden">`

then customer save but address not save.

But if added this code then above error is showing and redirect to register page.

Any idea guys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that's the only thing you did? This error appears when you are trying to delete certain entities from the frontend. The models for which you cannot do a delete action from frontend are category, product, customer, review, order, invoice, credit memo, shipping, store view, store group, website.

Comment: Yes,I only modified(re-arrange fields) on the register page and override register page in my custom module.

Comment: I have no idea what could have happened, but you can start debugging in `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::beforeDelete`. This is the only place where the error message appears in the code. Check what is Magento trying to delete and take ti from there. Or add what you find as details in your question.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

This error can be realted to **PHP compatibility** :

- For `Magento 2.3` : `PHP 7.1`
- For `Magento 2.2` : `PHP 7.1` or `PHP 7.0`
- For `Magento 2.1` : `PHP 7.1`, `PHP 7.0` or `PHP 5.6`
- For `Magento 2.0` : `PHP 7.0`, `PHP 5.6` or `PHP 5.5`

Check your PHP version, and upgrade or downgrade PHP if needed.

**You will never make Magento 2 works fine without the good version of PHP**

Comment: this is not helpful, you should help people with genuine responses, not generic things